# Get the actual line spacing and inter item spacing for a collection view?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

When you implement a collection view, you can specify the `minimumLineSpacing` and `minimumInteritemSpacing`, which will specify the minimum amount of padding to apply between rows and items in each row respectively, and iOS will automatically increase the amount of padding if needed to layout the items appropriately. My question is, how can you get the amount of actual padding applied? Once the view does appear, I need to calculate the real amount of padding between lines and between items.

Comment: Did you find a way to find it ? Instead of computing it ?

Comment: @RémyVirin I did not